# Kafka serialize-deserialize issue

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

We are using  java configuration for producer to achieve asynchronous retry mechanism

and on the consumer side we are using message driven adapter(xml configuration).

identify that in the producer side we have

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,MessageSerializer.class.getName());
```

on **producer** ,we dont have option for setting the **encoder** implementation as it only support the serializer interface implementation

**MessageSerializer implements Serializer**

and on the **consumer** side we don't have **deserialize** option as it only support decoder interface  implementation:

```
 <int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter

               id="inAdapter"
               channel="fromKafka"
               connection-factory="connectionFactory"
               key-decoder="kafkaKeyDecoder"
               payload-decoder="kafkaDecoder"                              
               topics="${topic.list}"
               offset-manager="offsetManager"/>
```

**kafkaDecoder implements Decoder**

Therfore getting error during serialization,can you please suggest on how to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of spring-integration-kafka; it is not configured that way anymore; the current version is 2.1.0 and it sits on top of spring-kafka 1.1.2.

The integration components are documented in the [spring-kafka reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_spring_integration). Configuring Spring Kafka itself is elsewhere in that book.